# How can I get state from selector after a page fresh?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga, selectors-api

I have a container component in react JS boilerplate code which gets data (let's say the list of schools) using sagas into reducer and sets a state to be read by the selector function in my render page to display to the user.

> saga.js sample data returned from the server

```
    data: [  {
                id: '1',
                name: 'School1',
                location: 'Location1',
             },
             {
                id: '2',
                name: 'School2',
                location: 'Location2',
             },
          ]
```

> actions.js snippet

```
    export function requestSchools() {
      return {
        type: REQUEST_SCHOOLS,
      };
    }
    export function requestSchoolsSucceeded(schoolsData) {
      return {
        type: REQUEST_SCHOOLS_SUCCEEDED,
        schoolsData,
      };
    }
```

> reducer.js snippet

```
    function schoolsContainerReducer(state = initialState, action) 
    {
      switch (action.type) {
        case REQUEST_SCHOOLS_SUCCEEDED:
           return state.set('schools', action.schoolsData);
        default:
           return state;
      }
    }
```

> selector.js snippet

```
    const makeSelectSchools = () =>
     createSelector(selectSchoolsContainerDomain, schoolState =>
     schoolState.get('schools'),
    );
```

> index.js snippet

```
    //This will trigger action REQUEST_SCHOOLS in action.js
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.props.requestSchools();
    }

    render() {
        const { schools } = this.props;

        const renderSch = schools.data.map(sch => (
          <div key={sch.id}>
            {sch.name} {sch.location}
          </div>
        ));
        return (
          <div>
            {renderSch}
          </div>
        );
      }

    const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
      schoolsContainer: makeSelectSchoolsContainer(),
      schools: makeSelectSchools(),
    });

    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
      return {
        //dispatch request schools action
        requestSchools: () => dispatch(requestSchools()),
      };
    }
```

At the first instance of building the web pack, I am able to get the data through and is able to render properly. However, when I refresh the same page, data comes until reducer (where the state is set) but not to the selector (where I get to state). How I can get data from reducer into selector after page refreshes?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, try to not use the componentWillMount method, since it is deprecated by React (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount)

I don't see why it wouldn't work on refresh. You might not need your selector as a function, and maybe you need a default value to ensure the validity of the map you're doing in React (Maybe this is the issue here?)

```
const makeSelectSchools = createSelector(
  selectSchoolsContainerDomain, // What is this doing? Getting the state of the previous reducer right?
  schoolState => schoolState.get('schools') || [],
);
```

And then call it in the container:

```
const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({ schools: makeSelectSchools });
```

Are you sure you don't have any more logs in your console? Or in the redux dev tools? It's quite difficult to debug as it is, and I personally don't see any reason for your app to be working only during the first load (if you don't manage any cache).

Hoping these little feedbacks will help you to narrow down your issue :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and I am not using componentWillMount method now. However, setting a default value does not solve the problem. In redux tool, all the actions called in the first instance (build) where everything gets rendered is also called when I am refreshing the page (manually). From my perception, problem is in selectors.js. It is not getting the state from the reducer after the page reloads. The reducer is however setting state and I am able to log it. When getting the state from selector the data is undefined.

Comment: I have managed to get the issue resolved. The reason was, initially, I was using a set data in saga.js without doing a fetch request call to the api server. After changing it, data was rendered on every page refresh and worked fine.